# Is there a way to create multiple @Client beans from a single class

Tags: java, kotlin, micronaut

I am trying to use a single Kotlin class to define multiple micronuat Client beans each with its own base url. I have a list of urls that correspond to several instances of the same webapp each of which have their own set of data, but all use the same rest endpoints. So I want to be able to spin up a bunch of client beans using the same base class, but each with its own name/url. Then in a service class I would be able to use the name to pull the bean from the application context.

The work around I have come up is below. In which you define a single abstractClient class, and then extend it many times with different client names. The problem with this is that I statically have to define all the possible names at compile time. I would like to be able to define some kind of map of config data in the yml of Name:URL pairs and have the clients auto generated

```
abstract class abstractClient (
  val name: String
){
  @Get(value = "/getStuff")
  abstract suspend fun getStuff()

@Client("client1")
abstract class Client1: abstractClient("name1")

@Client("client2")
abstract class Client2: abstractClient("name2")
```

I can then access the beans in my service class by injecting a List and looping through them looking for the right name

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to create multiple @Client beans from a single class

Not with a single class, no.

Answer (score 0):

If your same application deployed on multiple instances 
then your application resource path remains same for both the servers but only your application domain and port are different.
So in java it can be achieved by writing an interface having all resource client path/method and create separate classes which implements your common interface with different host URLs.

```
public interface Base{
  @Get(value = "/getStuff")
  public void getStuff();
}


@Client("client-1 url") // define client-1 url in yml
public class Client1 implements Base{}


@Client("client-2 url") // define client-2 url in yml
public class Client2 implements Base{}
```